# How can I use/map the field 'geoip.locations' in my index for Kibana which is looking for type 'geo_point'?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I have a log that returns a field called 'ip' from a parsed json field called 'message'.

I've set up my logstash.conf file as so:

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
  geoip {
    source => "ip"
    target => "geoip"
    #add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
    #add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}" ]
  }
  #mutate {
  #  convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float"]
  #}
}
```

However, I'm not seeing anything I can use in my index pattern to create a map. Kibana gives me the error:

```
The "myindex*" index pattern does not contain any of the following field types: geo_point
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: results of curl on /_mapping

```
{
  "<my index>": {
    "mappings": {
      "%{[@metadata][type]}": {
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "@version": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "host": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "message": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "tracking log": {
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "@version": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "accept_language": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "agent": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "beat": {
            "properties": {
              "hostname": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "version": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "context": {
            "properties": {
              "course_id": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "course_user_tags": {
                "type": "object"
              },
              "org_id": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "path": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "user_id": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "event": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "event_source": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "event_type": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "geoip": {
            "properties": {
              "city_name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "continent_code": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "coordinates": {
                "type": "float"
              },
              "country_code2": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "country_code3": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "country_name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "dma_code": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "ip": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "latitude": {
                "type": "float"
              },
              "location": {
                "type": "float"
              },
              "longitude": {
                "type": "float"
              },
              "postal_code": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "region_code": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "region_name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "timezone": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "host": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "input_type": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "ip": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "message": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "offset": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "page": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "referer": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "session": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "source": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "tags": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "time": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "username": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I used this command to execute the map:

```
curl -XPOST -u elastic 'localhost:9200/_template/<my index>' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{"order": 0, "template": "<my index>*","mappings": {"_default_": {"dynamic_templates": [{"location_fields": {"mapping": {"type": "geo_point"},"match": "geoip"}}]}}}
'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I solved this with the help of @Alcanzar. Apparently, as he said, it is impossible to change a the type of a field once data has been sent to it -- essentially, once you've started logstash and started using it.

So -- to map geoip.location to type geo_point -- here it what I did:

Steps:

1) I stopped logstash.

2) Deleted my index using 'DELETE /"

3) Created a new index with the name I wanted using 'PUT /' in the Kibana dev console.

4) Applied the mapping @Alcanzar contributed above using 'geoip.location' instead of 'location'

5) Restarted logstash.

Now geoip.location is of type geo_point.

It might be obvious that these are the steps to take for some of you experienced ES users, but it wasn't to me. I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `add_field` lines or the mutate/convert.  What you do need is to properly map the `geoip` field as a `geo_point` in elasticsearch.

Generally you'd do this with an index template -- this mapps any field named `geoip` to a `geo_point` -- you can be more specific with your templates though.

```
POST /_template/myindex
{
  "order": 0,
  "template": "myindex*",
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "location_fields": {
            "mapping": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            },
            "match": "location"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In any event, you'll need to re-index your data to get the mapping right and then tell kibana to reload your index mappings (under settings).

Comment: Ok -- did this. A curl on /_template shows it's in there but a curl on /_mapping isn't showing it. Where have I gone wrong? I do have all the geoid fields in my index now, but none are mapped to geo_point.

Comment: templates only apply at the point when the index is created (and there's no way to change the mapping of an existing field).  So you need to delete the index and re-index your data.

Comment: Ok -- did that. Still getting this error:  No Compatible Fields: The "<my index>*" index pattern does not contain any of the following field types: geo_point

Comment: Can you share the actual /myindex/_mapping to make sure the field is named correctly and that it exists?

Comment: Shared in the recent edit. Is it as simple as retarting the ES service? Or did I bork the POST?

Comment: i forgot that geo_ip creates a whole structure.  The `match` needs to be on `location` -- (it's been a while since I did this) -- updated my answer

Comment: Tried that too -- should it be "location" or "geoid.location"?

Comment: So -- i haven't fixed this yet -- but it turns out that if you're using Filebeat, which I am, then geoip.location isn't mapped to geo_point. It's a start...